# increase J48 tree size weka

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I'm doing Data Mining test where the tree size is not important to me.
Does somebody knows if there is a way to increase J48 tree size in WEKA, so that I will be able to reach bigger accuracy? or should I use other tree algorithm ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WEKA's J48 is an implementation oc the classic C4.5 tree induction algorithm. This algorithm makes use of an step called *pruning* in which some leaves and internal nodes are collapsed in order to avoid *overfitting*.

You can avoid this step by using the option `-U` ("use unpruned tree"). This way, the tree gets bigger, as no pruning is done.

However this step is nearly a must because overfitting. It is very likely that the tree you induce without pruning gets adapted too much to the training data, lacking of generalization and loosing accuracy on the actual data you will be using during classification.